# Why is the 'filters' set as (classes + 5) * 3 in this article?

Tags: computer-vision, config, yolo, darknet, custom-training

Here's a tutorial about doing custom training of YOLO (Darknet): https://medium.com/@manivannan_data/how-to-train-yolov3-to-detect-custom-objects-ccbcafeb13d2

The tutorial guides how to set values in the `.cfg` files:

- classes = Number of classes, OK
- filters = (classes + 5) * 3

**Why is it 'plus 5' then 'times 3'?**

Some say it's (classes + coords + 1) * num, but I can't guess it out the meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer,

```
filters = (classes + 5) * 3
= (classes + width + height + x + y + confidence) * num
= (classes + 1+1+1+1+1) * num
= (classes + 5) * num
```

YOLOv3 dectects 3 boxes per grid cell, so it is:

```
filters = (classes + 5) * 3
```