# Why yolov4 filter number are (classes + 5) * 3?

Tags: yolov4

I start to learn yolov4 this week and I don't know why filters = (classes + 5) * 3?
I think "3" is because there're 3 yolo layers in yolov4?
But I don't know what it means "classes + 5",why I need to use class Qty and add 5?
I can't find it in below pic .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52JXH.png)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60427903/why-is-the-filters-set-as-classes-5-3-in-this-article

Comment: oh sorry
I solved my question and forgot to reply.very thanks

Comment: You're welcome. You could add an Answer to your own Question if you have additional info details aside from the previously posted link that could possibly help others